# How to get access to the API testing console from the Azure cognitive services desktop?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'd like to get access to the API Testing console (the one mentioned in the Quick start of the Cognitive services translation services, useful to test the API without writing a single line of code), but I don't find any direct access to on the Microsoft Azure. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Which product are you talking about? Translation API?

Comment: yes, Translation API

Answer (score 1):

I think the text you mention about the console is a copy-paste error from other cognitive services quick start page.

Generally with `Cognitive Services`, you can find webpages which seems to be hosted under Azure API Management, where you got the basic documentation and access to a testing Console. For example for `West Europe`, all the services are here: https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/

And for `Anomaly Detector` API, you can see the link to the testing console:
[image: method with testing console link]

Sadly, it seems that there is not equivalent for Translator API.

You still have samples on Github that you can use, in several dev languages: https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator

Or you can directly call the API with a tool like Postman, it is really easy to implement